# Install APK from external_sd

Tags: installation, apk

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I've read that you can copy an APK file to the SD card and use the browser to activate the installer to install it with this:

file:///sdcard/yourApp.apk

(from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268803/android-how-to-install-apk-from-sd-card)

But, I cannot seem to get that to work with external_sd card. I've tried

file:///external_sd/yourApp.apk

I keep getting the following message:

"Data connectivity problem - The Web page contains an error."

Comment: Whats the message you are getting?  It also depends on how your sdcard is mounted.  Mine is mounted as 'sdcard' others are mounted as you mentioned 'external_sd'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Samsung phone, some of them have separate "internal" and "external" SD storage.  If it's on the external SD card, then you need this adress: file:///sdcard/external_sd/yourApp.apk

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the path being `/sdcard/external_sd` I thought it was just `/external_sd`

Comment: Yeah, Samsung is weird with their storage.

Comment: Thanks, I also didnt realize that you needed "sdcard" before "external_sd". Another thing that I just ran into - You can type in the following: file:///mnt/external_sd/yourApp.apk. That seems to work for me!

Comment: Yep, it's aliased.

Answer (score 5):

Try downloading a file explorer like [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result), find the apk and select it.  Android should prompt to install from there.

The selected answer you are referring to says to download [Astro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result) - which is another file manager. I'm not sure about the default Android browser though.